# Can I put everything in redux store in Angular?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am building an angular form. I have plenty of 'select' fields. The options for the select field should come from the server. Is it a good practice to store this information in the ngrx store. Or should I need to use just services and solve this problem.

Some of this dropdowns like currencies, countries etc are used in multiple places. I don't want to call server everytime as well. So If I put the options in the store, the store may grow large.

How efficiently can I solve this problem? How are you guys doing this?

Comment: You can easily add caching to Http observables if you know the data isn't going to change. I don't see this as an application state. What drop downs you show is a state, but caching the list of options so you don't have to load them later is a caching issue.

Comment: So, can I use just services in the component to load these options for the select field? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for this exact kind of thing that is much easier to use, reason about and setup than ngrx. Take a look at ngx-rxcache.

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache

It is a Behaviour Subject based lightweight cache that you can use to cache your server calls with in only a few lines of code rather than the ridiculous amount of boiler plate code required by ngrx.

This library was born out of dislike for ngrx and after having used it for the last few weeks I am confident that it is ready for other people to start using as well.

Check it out.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm using cache-factory now to cache my response.